Can't put image data into WriteableBitmap variable from xml file that I saved before
I have a problem with the reading of a WriteableBitmap data from xml that I previously saved.
Could you help me please?
Structure of data:
WriteableBitmap painter;
painter = new WriteableBitmap(
    pixelWidth: 100,
    pixelHeight: 100,
    dpiX: 96,
    dpiY: 96,
    pixelFormat: PixelFormats.Bgra32,
    palette: null);
byte[] sourcePixelData = new byte[] { 0, 0, 255, 255 };
Image image = new Image
{
    Source = painter,
    Width = painter.PixelWidth,
    Height = painter.PixelHeight
};

How I saved:
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(data.saveName, FileMode.Create))
using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(fs))
{
...
writer.WriteStartElement("itemSpecial");
PngBitmapEncoder encoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(painter));
using (MemoryStream _ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    encoder.Save(_ms);
    byte[] _imageBytes = _ms.ToArray();
    string _base64Image = Convert.ToBase64String(_imageBytes);
    writer.WriteStartElement("imageData");
    writer.WriteValue(_base64Image);
    writer.WriteEndElement();
}
writer.WriteEndElement();
...

}

The data from XML (it was just a few random moving of red brush under the image 100x100 pixels):
<itemSpecial>
    <imageData>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</imageData>
</itemSpecial>

How I try to read it:
byte[] _imageData = {0};
using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(data.loadName))
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        ...
        if (reader.Name == "imageData")
        {
            _imageData = Convert.FromBase64String(_str);
        }
        ...
        WriteableBitmap painter = new WriteableBitmap(100,100,96,96,System.Windows.Media.PixelFormats.Bgra32,null);
        var stride = (100 * painter.Format.BitsPerPixel + 7) / 8;
        var bufferSize = 100 * stride;
        painter.WritePixels(new System.Windows.Int32Rect(0, 0, 100, 100), _imageData, bufferSize, 0);
     ...
    }
}

The exception is: Not enough buffer size.
What I tried: to play directly with buffer size. (100 * painter.Format.BitsPerPixel + 7) / 8 is just a last variation, I also tried to put here thousands of bytes. I tried to re-save a new xml-file, but without success.

It looks like your question has more to do with serialization and deserialization from xml than it does with wpf and writeablebitmap. You may want to update your tags and also work on making a minimal reproducible example https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example that can help others reproduce the error you are seeing. At least one major item missing from your code is how _str is created that you are using to deserialize into your image data.

Unfortunately can't agree. In the reason I didn't know on which step I am wrong with my writeablebitmap object handling it was better to describe both side of the process. Yes it is inside se-/deserialization process, but in this case everything are about memory handling. I had a problem with (except my brain of course) concrete data type handling as I understand.

The base64 string contains an encoded PNG frame, not a raw pixel buffer. In order to create a WriteableBitmap from the string, you must first decode a BitmapSource:
WriteableBitmap painter;

using (var ms = new MemoryStream(_imageData))
{
    var decoder = BitmapDecoder.Create(
        ms, BitmapCreateOptions.None, BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad);

    painter = new WriteableBitmap(decoder.Frames[0]);
}

or
using (var ms = new MemoryStream(_imageData))
{
    var bitmap = BitmapFrame.Create(
        ms, BitmapCreateOptions.None, BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad);

    painter = new WriteableBitmap(bitmap);
}

or
using (var ms = new MemoryStream(_imageData))
{
    var bitmap = new BitmapImage();
    bitmap.BeginInit();
    bitmap.StreamSource = ms;
    bitmap.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
    bitmap.EndInit();

    painter = new WriteableBitmap(bitmap);
}


Thank you for your support. It helped. My problem was that during search in google and ask of copilot I saw the solution that I provided and seems I didn't read good about WriteableBitmap class.
